# Anonymous access IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

Please can someone help me understand anonymous access in IIS. I know by when IIS is installeled an account is created called IUSR_*ComputerName*  but does this mean that I have to add and the user to root directory of the website if anoymous is enabled. I've also read that on a server even though the IUSR_*ComputerName* is used, it acutally used a network service user. If so do I have to grant this user permissions to the directory?

Finally, as the user password is not managed by windows, is there a tool I can use to reset this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user password is managed by Windows.  You can change it as a regular Windows user but probably shouldn't.

If you are dealing with an ASP.NET application it will not really (I think...) use that anonymous user.  It will run as the identity of the application pool, which is NetworkService until Windows 2008R2 and after Windows 2008R2 became ApplicationPoolIdentity (by default, you change it back to NetworkService in the AppPool settings/Identity).

The AppPoolIdentity differs from NetworkService in that it doesn't have access to network (i.e. shares on other computers).  If you do need to access them, change back to Network Service.  The shares will be accessed with the identity of the computer on which you are running your app.

If your app needs to write to its directory you will need to grant NetworkService rights to it.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm using windows 2003 so I'll be using network service. So regardless of the credentials I put in the anonymous section, it will always use networkservice?

Comment: @mjroodt see also this http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount I think it is correct... basically, if you don't enable impersonation (and I suggest you don't for various reasons), app pool identity is all you need to know about.

Comment: Thanks, read the page and it is very useful but I've tried the following. My website which is an Intanet has Integrated windows authentication enabled on the root however as my website is a cms system (Ektron), they require one particular folder to have anonymous access enabled, this folder is called workarea. In IIS I enable anonymous access on this folder and the username is IUSR_MYCOMPUTERNAME and just to make sure, I reset the password for that user and type it in.

Comment: The site is using an application pool and runs as network service but  when I access the workarea, it says I'm not authorised to view the page. So in ACL I add in network service and IUSR_COMPUTERNAME (full permissions) to the workarea folder and its children. Still not authorised to view this page, so finally I put my credentials in the anonymous username i.e. DOMAIN\mjroodt, type my windows password in and I then have access to view the page. So my question is, what permission do I have to grant the folder for my local anonymous account to view the page. Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Check IIS logs for an exact error code including subcode, also check event viewer for possible authentication failures.